# Mysql indexing : best practices whith query builder

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-builder

We have tables that contain millions of data. We intend to create indexes on this table to optimize the search.

The issue here is that the 11 filters on this table are variable, which means that the user can choose one or multiple filters. In the end, the columns on the where clause can change by number and order in the query

What is the best practice to create the index??

Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems like a BI application, which tend to cache large amounts of data in memory and perform searching on the cached data as opposed to retrieve everything from the database on the fly every time. If you wanted to use indexes to speed up every search, then you would have to create an index for each possible field combination, which is not viable given the number of fields.

Comment: Select 3-5 columns or columns combinations which are used most often, and index by it. It is unreal to create an index for each possible filters combination...

Answer (score 0):

For long text, use FULLTEXT.

For numbers and short strings, use INDEX.

Study what users are likely to search on, then build several 2-column indexes.  Come back with names of such columns; I'll help you a further.

Comment: My table contains varchars of 36 characters and 10 characters and booleans. Would you explain the 2 column indexes?

Comment: @blue - Composite indexes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: thank you, yes I know well about composite indexes, I asked about the choice of the number 2, As I posted, the query may contain more than 2 column

Comment: @blue - "every possible combination" would [I assume] lead to a huge number of indexes--probably more than can be handled by MySQL.  A 'reasonable' number is 5-10 indexes.  But that does not leave much room for lots of combos.  "2" is not magical; it is another Rule of Thumb to help you focus on finding a limited number of semi-optimal indexes.

Comment: @blue - Also,...  Going beyond "2" is getting into "diminishing returns".